# Serialise an object and deserialize it into a different one - WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, deserialization

In my system, I am trying to provide the client with a minimal class definition of a given module (as the client should not be aware of the full implementation of that module). On the service side, the equivalent class will have extra/different methods and properties (to be known from the service only).

Now, I am not quite sure what is the best way to do that in WCF, but I thought I could maybe serialise/deserialise 2 slightly different objects back and forth. Let's take these 2 mildly different objects as an example:

```
// Given to the client
public class SomeClass
{
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public int MinValue { get; set; }
   public int MaxValue { get; set; }
}

// Internal to the service
public class SomeClass
{
   // !!! Note that I might also want the getter and setter to do different things here than in previous class
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public int MinValue { get; set; }
   public int MaxValue { get; set; }

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      // Do something
      // ...
   }
}
```

Note sure the concept is any good, but any suggestion on how this is to be done would be welcome.

Comment: The objects in the serialize class has to match the class in the deserialize class.  So if you make the properties that you do not want serialized private then the client will not get these properties.  You also may want to use the preprocessor directives to compile a different version for client : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/

Comment: Are you saying I should compile 2 versions of the same class? One with the Private methods and one without?

Comment: Either that or create a case class with properties you want to give client and then put your private values in the inherited class.

Comment: Thanks, are you saying, use the base class (without private methods defined) for the client and deserialise into a derived class that defines the Private methods (that inherit from the base class) on the service side? Then cast deserialised object to derived class in order to use private methods? Not sure that will work!?

Comment: The client only needs the base class properties and no derived class.  So no casting would be required.